# Did ibn Tayymiyah indirectly allow fasting 31 days of Ramadan?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, islamic-scholar

Once I've heard a lesson from a scholar in a mosque. And he pretended that ibn Taymiyyah held the opinion that a person must start fasting Ramadan with the community and the people at the location he was at the sighting of the hilal (new crescent moon) and he must remain fasting with the community and the people at the location he was at the time the hilal for Shawwal was sighted.

Now this would mean that it is possible to fast based on the calcuclations of the Turkish minister of Islamic affairs and apparently also the Umm al-Qura Calendar with the first possible sighting of a crescent moon somewhere on earth and travel to a country that actually relys on local moonsighting which has started Ramadan 1 or 2 days later. Commonly it is known from the sunnah that a month has either 29 or 30 days so one shouldn't fast one day more if one has already performed 30 days of fasting.
What if the location one moved to is still fasting a day more? That would mean one would fast 31 days according to the above description.

My question is:

Is the description made by that scholar about ibn Taymiyyah's view correct and where is it quoted?
Does ibn Taymiyyah suggest an option for the case of need to fast 31 days- described above due to travel during Ramadan-?